# Parse Multiple Json Array Elements in Oracle

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I have to parse below json in oracle that contain array element as showing below

```
{"orgPhoneNum":[["9952044727"],["5464646464"]]}
```

I tried below statement

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"orgPhoneNum":[["9952044727"],["5464646464"]]}', '$.orgPhoneNum') 
  FROM DUAL;
```

that return the result like

[image]

But i want to get the result like

```
9952044727,5464646464
```

What changes i will need to put in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the array values using `JSON_TABLE` and then aggregate using `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG( orgPhoneNum, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY row_number )
         AS orgPhoneNums
FROM   JSON_TABLE(
         '{"orgPhoneNum":[["9952044727"],["5464646464"]]}',
         '$.orgPhoneNum[*][*]'
         COLUMNS (
           row_number FOR ORDINALITY,
           orgPhoneNum VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$'
         )
       )
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | ORGPHONENUMS          |
> | :-------------------- |
> | 9952044727,5464646464 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9820e34242e13f1862e9d4c1e453a8f1)*